# Assigning type of a dynamically generate variable to a list in a loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set of technical indicators in a list - indicator_list = [ema10,ema20,...]
I am trying to generate a indicator series list which will hold the series value for each stock for each indicator as below -

```
indicator_ser_dict = {}
for indicator in indicator_list:
   indicator_ser_list = indicator + '_ser_list'
   indicator_ser_dict[indicator] = indicator_ser_list
```

How do I set the type of each indicator_ser_list to a list. That is each of the value in the indicator_ser_dict needs to be a list.
Please note that indicator_ser_list needs to be treated as a variable and not a string.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements. Do you want to add to the dictionary a key and value pair where the key is the indicator name and the value is a list of length 1 containing the string of the indicator name concatenated with the string "_ser_list"?

Comment: @Aretle, I want to create a dictionary containing an indicator and indicator series variable (only with no values). The indicator series variable needs to be of type list and needs to be an empty list which would be populated later on with series(one series for each stock). Hope this clarifies

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification. So would the expected output for an inidcator list = [ema10, ema20] be a dictionary that is {'ema10': [], 'ema20': []}?

Comment: @Aretle, the expected output would be a dictionary  {'ema10':'ema10_ser_list','ema_20':'ema20_ser_list',...}, where each of the *_ser_list needs to be of type list and empty. These *_ser_list values would be populated with series later on.

Comment: The problem with this expected output is that you can't have a string be a list type (unless the list is of each character in the string which I'm sure you don't want). Would this expected output work for your needs? {'ema10':'ema10_ser_list', ema10_ser_list: [], 'ema_20':'ema20_ser_list', ema_20_ser_list: []...}

Comment: Thanks @Aretle for your time to look into the issue I am facing. I agree with you. The problem is that I am trying to create a variable but generating a string. What you are suggesting is to have a pair of key , value for each indicator. In that case how will I access/get the indicator_ser_list value given a specific indicator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: No worries @Prem Ji. Given an indicator name you could get the list using two calls to the dictionary. list_key = indicator_ser_dict[indicator_name]; indicator_ser_list = indicator_ser_dict[list_key]. Alternatively, you could just assign the list straight to the key of the indicator name with indicator_ser_dict[indicator] = [] in your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following method:

```
indicator_ser_dict = {}
for indicator in indicator_list:
    indicator_ser_list = indicator + '_ser_list'
    indicator_ser_dict[indicator] = indicator_ser_list
    indicator_ser_dict[indicator_ser_list] = []
```

With input list: `[ema10, ema20]` The output dictionary will look like:

```
indicator_ser_dict = {
    ema10: 'ema10_ser_list',
    ema10_ser_list = [],
    ema20: 'ema20_ser_list',
    ema20_ser_list = []
}
```

**Alternatively**, you could declare the list variable directly into the name of the indicator:

```
indicator_ser_dict = {}
for indicator in indicator_list:
    indicator_ser_dict[indicator] = []
```

For output dictionary:

```
indicator_ser_dict = {
    ema10: [],
    ema20: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you right.
I understand that you want every item-value in your indicator_ser_dict to be a single item list.

Given your examples, having ema10,ema20 as input you want to put ema10 into a list and place this single-item-list as value in the dictionary.

You can simply put the item to be listed into square brackets:

```
indicator_ser_dict = {}
for indicator in indicator_list:
   indicator_ser_list = [indicator + '_ser_list'] #-> makes indicator_ser_list  to be a list of one element
   indicator_ser_dict[indicator] = indicator_ser_list
```

Since ure concatenating a string to each indicator, the indicator_ser_list of course always was a string. Now its a List of a single string.

Comment: The indicator_ser_list variable that is created in the for loop, needs to be an empty list. This indicator_ser_list list will be populated later on but not at this stage.